# Logging on SD-card in Android

Tags: java, android, sd-card

How can we save log-file of our application actions on SD-card?

We should have a file created everyday:

- the name of the file should have a date format

  - file name should be current date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()** use this to get the path of SD card and then get today's date, convert it to string and concat it with SD card path.  Use the concatenated string to create a **File** and write your log using **FileOutputStream** or **FileWriter**.

Answer (score 0):

In that case i suggest usage of XML files.
Pretty simple to save and load data.

Build class that will take care of all XML routine. Each time you want to save you activy, just call for  appropriate method in this class. Method will prepare all data you need, and create file based on date you required.